# Behaviour problems

Tags: cats, stress

I'm a newbie and amateur with pets. My cats are male triplets and they are 10 months old. One of them start peeing or spraying around the house and I think he might be stressed out for being unable to mate. However, the other two are fine. Besides, there are feral cats that came to the house area and attacked him. His peeing start getting worse and it's become a daily habit. He even sprayed his pee at my leg. He doesn't like to be held either and loses appetite. We also have new cats in the house, but he start peeing before that and fighting with his brother instead of the new one. So what should I do to stop his behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

## The simple answer is to get them neutered.

Unless you really want them to stay bad-tempered and spray pungent gunk everywhere...

You might want to check out this [FAQ](http://www.cats.org.uk/neutering-faqs)